# C++ Standard Functors Have Non-Static Operators

Tags: c++, static, function-pointers, functor, member-functions

So I notice that C++ functors, such as `plus` have non-`static` operators: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus#Member_functions

Because the `template <typename T> T plus::operator()(const T&, const T&)` is non-`static` I can not pass it or assign it to a function pointer.

For example I just want to be able to assign `plus<int>::operator()` to:

```
int (*foo)(const int&, const int&)
```

But I cannot because it is a member function. Obviously I can write a lambda here to do this, I just wanted to know if there had been any discussion on making the `operator()` `static`.

Comment: Calling it could look strange: `my_functor::()`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah I closed this when I read the linked questions answers. It looks like this has been explicitly disallowed by C++. So yeah, none of that strange look in C++!